# The @wix/sdk package is not working correctly with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, velo

I'm trying to use wix Oauth in my react app, so i used @wix/sdk-react (that based on @wix/sdk), but where i starts this project, i have this problems.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az21z.png)

It seems like one of the modules tries to get another part of code from /src/, but this package have only /build/ directory.

The code sample:
`import { WixProvider, OAuthStrategy } from '@wix/sdk-react';

function App() {
const [examples, setExamples] = useState([]);

return (
<WixProvider
auth={OAuthStrategy({
clientId: '%my_id_here',
})}

> 

)
}`

I updated my node and npm, and tried to use @wix/api-client (their deprecated package), but it didn't help me.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.